# How to test old linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

We can change OS kernel, ex: CentOS, by 'yum update kernel-xxxx'

However, I think we can not downgrade the kernel to an old version.

The purpose is to test the old kernel ( ex: 0.11, 0.96, 2.0 ....etc )

Is there any way to test it without OS bundle(ex: CentOS)? ( especially I want to test it with VirtualBox )

Comment: Wrong forum. Go superuser

Comment: Some distributions could have archives going back to very earliest versions of the distribution. Exactly how far back and what kernel versions might be used, depends on distribution. It should also be possible to find archives of older but now defunct distributions.

Comment: If you use virtualization and have enough disk space the simple way is of course to save all the necessary versions separately. Anyway it is useless to save all the minor versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really old versions can still be found from Funet. For example:

http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/old-versions/

I installed `0.95a` back in the day from floppies, but after over a quarter century can't remember all the details. Point is: You don't need a distribution, those came much later. And I'm sure no recent distro would run with those old kernels and `glibc`s.

You should create a bootable floppy (or an image of one for your VM) from an `bootimage/rootimage`. No need to precompile. I think you'll get shell and not much more, all the GNU stuff you have to install separately.

Search for *Linux Frequently Asked Questions* monthly posts in `comp.os.linux` usenet archive:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.os.linux/ZbiUmhnkjIY/y_OADLVPxooJ

Comment: I think we can still get the old version of kernel from kernel.org. My problem is, I don't know how to install it? just compile and run it in current OS, ex: CentOS 7?

Comment: No, the thing installs to i386 system from bootable floppy. Edited the answer.

Comment: I guess the old kernel compile output is an execution binary, how to setup it on a floppy? Ex, today, we have grub, do we need other tools?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is answering your question 100% but I will give it a try. 
You can download/clone an old version of the linux kernel here [kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/refs/heads). 
The oldest version is 2.6.11 (as far as I found). I hope this meets your expectations. 
 This source/tarbal needs to be build and installed [Tutorial](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/).

Please be careful, many things could go wrong and it might take some time to do it the way you want. I never tried these steps in a VM, so I am not sure if this is possible.

---EDIT---
You can find even older kernel version in the archiv and here is a link to 2.4.x [Archiv](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/)

Comment: No, I don't think it will work, at least the driver didn't match kernel API, I guess. For CentOS, we can get CentOS 2.1 which used kernel 2.4.9. http://vault.centos.org/2.1/source/i386/SRPMS/ .However, I want to test with even older version, I try to test it standalone without OS bundle.

Comment: @Mark I added one extra link with your desired kernel version. I hope this might help you in some way.

Comment: Hi xMutzelx, thanks, I think we can get all version of kernel here: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/ and https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/old-versions/

Answer (score 0):

bump.  in tonight's quest to find the oldest sysvinit available, I have run across a few files (mirror while hot!):  https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/bin/tools-old/  notably [init.c](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/bin/admutil-1.4.tar.Z) and [sysvinit-2.0](https://ftp.funet.fi/pub/linux/tools/sysvinit.tar.Z).  (use mkdir before unpacking.)  such versions appear in the release notes for linux-0.95 and the [changelog](https://fossies.org/linux/sysvinit/doc/Changelog#l_1157) for sysvinit.  you will need an extra-old gcc to compile them.  when done, use an old-style ext2 partition, and place in the location /bin/init or /etc/init from the release notes.  make sure you have /dev/console and /dev/tty*  ;with earlier kernels, the file init/init.c performs this function.  let me know if you'd like me to try this myself sometime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I tacked this problem with a slightly different twist.  I wanted to use the vintage tools on Windows to cross compile and test old Linux kernels.  My goal was to use something that didn’t require Cygwin or WSL, but rather msys and MinGW.  The result of this project is at source forge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/linux011/

From my own blurb:
While I may have started with Linux 0.11, I've expanded this to include several older relases of the Linux kernel that you can cross compile from Windows, and run on Qemu. I've managed to get the older versions of the software tools running on Windows, so that there is no major invasive source changes, outside of either broken drivers, or massaging the makefiles to find things in the new paths, and calling the appropriate tools where needed.

Linux 0.10 is the first oldest version of Linux that is somewhat usable. While it lacks things like TCP/IP, and robust filesystems, it does offer a small kernel size, perfect for playing around with. You can comfortably make changes on Windows, re-compile and test all from a 'normal' desktop.

Features
GCC 1.40
GCC 2.3.3
GCC 2.5.8
Binutils 1.9
GAS 1.38
Bison 1.16

So from windows the following cross compilers can build working kernels, and it even includes qemu environmental with scripts to run all the old versions.

There is no installer just unzip and edit “env.cmd” to reflect the installed directory.  From there you can look in the source tree and run make and it’ll build the kernel from you.  Inside the qemu directory is a cmd file tailored to run each version that I’ve setup to cross compile.

Naturally you can use any windows editor on the source, which was my original goal to bring Linux kernel development to the casual Windows desktop user.

Source to the tools is also included I used GCC 5 and msys/ Mingw to build everything.  I think GCC 7 may work but it’s been a while.